# Mysql single values from a table insert into a new table

Tags: mysql

I have a big issue, because I don't know how I can put a singles Value from a table into a new table. Here are the construct of the invoice, how I upload it:

[image]

**Edit:** I give the comment below right, you need more information. I tell you my steps:

The values I need for my work are in a invoice, so  I upload this invoice in my database. In the first screenshot you will see the only the construct of the invoice. The values stand for price and a item number. But I need only the prices and the item number. So I have to put these three value in a new table

This is my goal:

[image]

Comment: Do you feel your question is brief enough for others to answer?

Comment: From your requirement, basically you are trying to achieve PIVOT. Have a look on this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score -1):

```
 insert into table_1(col1,col2,col3,col4)
 select value1 as col1, value2 as col2, value3 as col3, value4 as col4 from table_2
```

Make sure the columns names of table_2 much match the columns names of table1 (in which you are inserting the values)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it was my fall. I doesn't give you the informationens you need.

Comment: Table1 has the details, and I want to put it in table2. Thank you for your help

Comment: then select columns from table1 and add in table2, just modify the above query as per your needs

Comment: okay, how can i get the scond price in the first row ? this is the main problem I think to get itemnumber-price1-price2